# AngularJS tooltip show or hide

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I use AngularJS tooltip and it works fine. Now I will have a condition wheather tooltip should be shown or not. Is there any attribute to do this?

```
<div data-popover-template="'chartTimePopoverTemplate.html'" data-popover-trigger="mouseenter" data-ng-repeat="scheduleIntervalContainer in ...
<script type="text/ng-template" id="chartTimePopoverTemplate.html">
    <div">
        {{scheduleIntervalContainer.startTime}} - {{scheduleIntervalContainer.endTime}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
popover-is-open="booleanValue"
```

as shown in the docs [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#popover).